# JUI Extension for Yii 2 can not be installed

Tags: yii, composer-php, yii2

I want to install JUI Extension for Yii 2, but composer reports me the following issues:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.


    - yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.4 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.3 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.2 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.1 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2-jui 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/jquery-ui 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-jui ^2.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-jui[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4].

    Potential causes:
    - A typo in the package name
    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
    see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

What I can do in order to fix this?

Answer (score 11):

Finally I found the solution:

If you want to install the JUI extension for Yii2, you should do the following steps:

1. Run the following composer command: `php composer.phar require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0"`
2. Run  `php composer.phar update`
3. Run  `php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui`

Comment: it doesn't helo me. composer downloaded a lot of things, updated so many things. but , anyway it gives the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while I was trying to install Kartik's extension for Yii2 framework. Adding `"fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "*"` to the **require** section of my **composer.json** file solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Need to install the Composer Asset Plugin first:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0"
```

This one worked for me